# Can someone explain how $3^{n+1} + 3^n = 4 \cdot3^n$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Slow morning. 
Can someone help me figure it out? I have a feeling it is trivially easy and not worthy of a thread.
$$
3^{n+1} + 3^n = 4\cdot3^n
$$

Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean $4\times 3^n$? I.e. $3^n$ instead of $3n$.

Comment: Yes. Edited. . .

Comment: When I have a very slow morning, I use [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve[3^%28n%2B1%29%2B3n%3D%3D4*3^n]) ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Answers this version of the question**

The previous version of the question claimed that for all $n \in \Bbb N$, $$3^{n+1}+3n=4\cdot 3n \tag{1}$$

However $(1)$ is not true for all $n$ as noted in the next part of the answer.

> However what is true is: $$3^{n+1}+3^n=4\cdot3^n$$
>
> To see this, note that $3^{n+1}=3^n \cdot 3$ and factor the $3^n$ out.

**Answers the previous version of the question**

Your claim is simply not true. For $n=2$, LHS equals $ 33$ while RHS evaluates to $24$.

Comment: Christ. I am stupid. Thanks

Comment: No you are not. But this feeling can make you one. So, please do not think this way, Regards,

Answer (score 7):

**Hint**: Write $3^{n+1}$ as $3\cdot 3^n$, then factor $3^n$ out of the sum.

(I assume the question is about $3^{n+1}+3^n$.)